Distance between a Hölder function and a Sobolev ball
Let $\Omega$ denote $[0, 1]^n$ and let $\|\cdot\|_{k, p}$ and $|\cdot|_{m, \alpha}$ denote norms of Sobolev space $W^{k,p}(\Omega)$ and Holder space $C^{m, \alpha}(\Omega)$, respectively.
My question is how far a Holder function is from a Sobolev function, specifically
$$
\Delta (n, m, \alpha, k, p, t) =\sup_{|u|_{m, \alpha} \leq 1} \inf_{\|f\|_{k,p} \leq t} \|f - u\|_{L^2(\Omega)}
$$
That is, the worst-case distance of a map $u \in C^{m, \alpha}(\Omega)$ with $|u|_{m, \alpha} \leq 1$ from the set of function $f \in W^{k,p}(\Omega)$ with $\|f\|_{k, p} \leq t$.
Is this quantity known (up to constants)? If so, what are the relevant references?
